# Seed Ruby DataBase From AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket containing a bunch of data in the format of a Ruby Hash. What I'd like to do upon running `rails s` is to have the data retrieved from the S3 bucket and use that to seed the database. The data in the S3 bucket will always be changing and the Rails app is running inside of a container so I'm going to need to seed the DB before every run. How do I seed a database from an S3 bucket?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: One option can be to create a rake task that downloads the s3 file(s) and then seed your database (there is a gem for [s3](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-s3/versions/1.114.0) . But, yeah, what is your question? Is it how to download the file? or how to use a hash to see a database? or something else?